# Coding Challenge Solution - Find Number of Elements in a range in \$O(1)\$ with preprocessing

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, hash-map

## Overview

This is my solution to the following [Coding Challenge - Find Num of Elements in a Range in \$O(1)\$ with Preprocessing](https://www.careercup.com/question?id=5702311087702016) -

> Given an array and max element in the array, find the number of elements present
>   between a given range in \$O(1)\$. You can do one-time processing of an array.

## Solutions

### Solution1

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Solution 
{
    public: 
    Solution(vector<int>& v) 
    {
        sort(v.begin(), v.end()); 

        for(unsigned int i=0; i<v.size(); ++i) m[v[i]] = i; 
    }

    unsigned int count(const int a, const int b)
    {       
        if(!(a < b)) throw runtime_error("Wrong Order"); 
        if( (m.find(a) == m.end()) || (m.find(b) == m.end()) ) throw runtime_error("Not Found"); 
        return m[b] - m[a] + 1; 
    }

    private: 
    unordered_map<int, unsigned int> m; 
}; 

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int N; 
    cin >> N; 
    vector<int> data; 
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) 
    {
        int temp; 
        cin >> temp; 
        data.push_back(temp); 
    }

    Solution sol(data); 
    const auto left = 1; 
    const auto right = 3; 
    const auto res = sol.count(left, right); 
    cout << "Left = " << left << ", Right = " << right << " --> Res = " << res << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Input

```
10 
1 3 5 7 9 6 2 8 12 22
```

**Notes**

- Even if typically for Algorithmic Coding Challenges a free function is good enough and using a class is over-engineering, in this specific I went for the class on purpose in order to possibly amortize the pre-processing cost by multiple calls to the `count()` method.

### Solution2

This is an **Edit** in order to propose an alternative solution based on @peter-taylor comment about the range

This solution does not throw an exception in case the values in the input range are not in the array and it is still $O(1)$ in time, just added more space complexity

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Solution 
{
    public: 
    Solution(vector<int>& v) 
    {       
        sort(v.begin(), v.end()); 
        start = v[0]; 
        end = v[v.size()-1]; 

        unsigned int count=1; 
        unsigned int j=1; 

        for(int i=start; i<end; ++i)
        {
            if(i==v[j]) 
            {
                count++; 
                j++; 
            }

            m[i] = count; 
        }
    }

    unsigned int count(const int a, const int b)
    {
        if(!(a < b)) throw runtime_error("Wrong Order");         
        return get_num(b) - get_num(a); 
    }

    private: 
    unordered_map<int, unsigned int> m;
    int start; 
    int end; 

    unsigned int get_num(const int a)
    {
        if(a < start) return 0 ; 
        if(a >= end) return m.size(); 
        return m[a]; 
    }
}; 

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int N; 
    cin >> N; 
    vector<int> data; 
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) 
    {
        int temp; 
        cin >> temp; 
        data.push_back(temp); 
    }

    Solution sol(data); 
    const auto left = 0; 
    const auto right = 3; 
    const auto res = sol.count(left, right); 
    cout << "Left = " << left << ", Right = " << right << " --> Res = " << res << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

**Notes**

- In this implementation the number of elements is computed in a `(a,b]` range (so first not counted) as this is not violating anything in the specs

Comment: This looks obviously buggy to me - the spec says nothing to justify the `throw`. What test cases did you use to test it?

Comment: Why buggy? 
As the specs do not specify that case it's undefined behaviour (and I managed it in a reasonable way). 
It does not make sense to test undefined behaviours in test cases

Comment: The spec says "*a given range*". It's not reasonable to say that since it doesn't *explicitly* say "*a given range whose endpoints might not be in the array*" it *must* mean "*a given range whose endpoints are in the array*".

Comment: OK @PeterTaylor I have added Solution 2 according to your observation: still O(1) in time but more space complexity